# how to create an instance of store in controller in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4

i want to call store of a chart from the init() function in controller. I want to create an instance of store of a chart in the controller. here is my code ..

```
Ext.define('Gamma.controller.ControlFile', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  //define the stores
  stores: ['BarColumn', 'RadarView', 
           'VoiceCallStore', 'SMSCallStore', 
           'MMSCallStore', 'GPRSUsageStore'],
  //define the models 
  models: ['BarCol', 'radar', 
           'VoiceCallModel', 'SMSCallModel', 
           'MMSCallModel', 'GPRSUsageModel'],
  //define the views
  views: ['BarColumnChart', 'LineChart', 
          'RadarChart', 'VoicePie', 
          'SMSPie', 'MMSPie', 'GPRSPie'],
  init: function () {
    this.control({});
  }
});
```

Please any one help me..

Answer (score 2):

That's an easy one:

`var store = this.getStore('storeName');`

Where `this` is your controller.

See: [Ext.app.Controller.getStore documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getStore)

Comment: thank you for your response.But where should i place this line?? inside init()??

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible. Where do you need it?